# File Download from Popup on ASPX Page Via generic Handler

Tags: asp.net, popup, handler, httpresponse, generic-handler

My aspx page has a Download link. On click of it a popup occurs asking user to enter some data based on which the file is modified before getting downloaded.

I have forwarded the request made by the pop up to a generic handler which is having code to generate a file and append it into the response header.

Now, I am getting a thread abort exception as Could not able to evaluate expression because code is optimized or a native frame is on top of call stack.

I guess the response header was not interpreted by the client because of the pop up.
Please find the code snippet and tell me where I am going wrong :

ASPX for Popup Button:

```
 <button id="BtnDownload" class="btnSubmit" onclick="javascript:downloadFileViaHandler()">
                                        Download</button>
```

Javascript Function:

```
function downloadFileViaHandler() {
$('#popupdiv').dialog('close');
var urlHandler = "/WebHandlers/downloadHandler.ashx";
var urlHandlerParam = window.location.href.split('/');
var actualUrlparam = urlHandlerParam[0] + "/" + urlHandlerParam[1] + "/" + urlHandlerParam[2] + "/" + urlHandlerParam[3];
//Sanitize URLs for Server     
var urlHandler = actualUrlparam + urlHandler;
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  async: false,      
  url: urlHandler,
  data: { FileID: '' + FileID + '\'' },
  success: function (data) {
      console.info(data);
      },
  error: function () {
      alert("Error occured while Downloding File");
  }
  });
```

}

Handler Code:

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
 {  
   //some Logic to generate file//

 string filePath = str_SaveFileLocation;
 DownloadFilePath = (str_SaveFileLocation); 
 string name = Path.GetFileName(DownloadFilePath);
 string ext = Path.GetExtension(DownloadFilePath); 
 string Filetype = "text/DBC";
 context.Response.Clear();
 context.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "Downloads;   filename=" + name);
 context.Response.ContentType = Filetype;
 context.Response.WriteFile(DownloadFilePath);
 context.Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `ThreadAbortException` is normal when you call `Response.End().` See [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end(v=vs.110).aspx).

> To mimic the behavior of the End method in ASP, this method tries to
>   raise a [ThreadAbortException] exception. If this attempt is
>   successful, the calling thread will be aborted, which is detrimental
>   to your site's performance. In that case, no code after the call to
>   the End method is executed. If the End method is not able to raise a
>   [ThreadAbortException], it instead flushes the response bytes to the
>   client. It does this synchronously, which can also be detrimental to
>   your site's performance.